# Extract PYZ Error

Tags: decompilation, elf, python

I successfully recovered some PYC files from an ELF built by PyInstaller (https://github.com/extremecoders-re/pyinstxtractor/wiki/Extracting-Linux-ELF-binaries). There is a PYZ archive in the dump. I tried to use pyi-archive_viewer to open and/or extract some modules from the PYZ. I receive an AttributeError "ZlibArchive object has no attribute open openEmbedded."

The error occurs on line 134 of the source (https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/blob/develop/PyInstaller/utils/cliutils/archive_viewer.py)

I believe something is incorrectly parsed/output during extraction...? Has anyone else seen this?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else this happens to... Ensure you use the same Python version as the original author.

That is, I originally created the ELF with Python 3.7. But I tried the reversing process on a different machine - with Python 3.8. Learn from my mistake!

Comment: I'm curious on how did you discover that it was a mismatching Python version issue? Was it coincidence? Or you've done some kind of static analysis to the source code of the python files and figured it out?

Comment: a dash of trial and error, and a dash of reading the python release notes. though I cannot recall what tipped me off in the latter :/

Comment: That was definitely a nice and thorough learning experience, thanks for sharing the answer!